# How to install pycrypto 2.6 in python 3.2 in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, python3

how do i find and install Pycrypto 2.6 to python 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04, i have looked everywhere for a package, i managed to get it installed on python 2.7 just fine, but i want be able to use the lib in 3.2. Program in both and want to be able to use it in both, thank you.

im running:

Ubuntu 12.04,
Acer Aspire 5920,
3 gb ram

Answer (score 0):

i am terribly sorry, but it can't be done. there is one site that claims to have done it, but i have not tried it as others say it does not work. here is the link for the site :
http://lists.dlitz.net/pipermail/pycrypto/2010q1/000198.html

hope this helps, even a little :)

Comment: i found that if i uninstall python 2.7, then apt-get install pycrypo, it installed fine, it had been ported, i already knew that